# export 'default' (imported as 'Firebase') was not found in './Firebase' (possible exports: auth, db)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have the file name Firbase.js, I'm trying to import it into my react app but I'm getting an error.
my firebase SDK version is above 9 and tried all possible solutions out there regarding this problem(like added compact) still getting the same error.

```
import Firebase from "./Firebase";
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCs4EVlGZyp196rW1LEgaFoqEPGEdsLCaQ",
    authDomain: "eshop-44152.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "eshop-44152",
    storageBucket: "eshop-44152.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "66308486492",
    appId: "1:66308486492:web:b29fb678562d180870fd99",
    measurementId: "G-SSMTNCXPD9"
  };
const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

const auth = Firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

packages:

```
    "firebase": "^9.8.3",
    "firebase-login": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.1.0",
```

Comment: Can you share your import statement ?

Comment: Did you make Firebase.js, if so, does it have a default export?

Comment: No, it has no default export

Comment: I'm importing it in login.js   ```import {auth} from './Firebase'